# Problems with a form in SocialEngine/Zend

Tags: php, database, zend-framework, socialengine

I have created a module in SocialEngine(*which is built on Zend framework v1.9) that contains an admin form with a few options.

The problem I have with it is that it seems to no get the values of the fields from database after I refresh the page and it shows me the default values.

It shows the correct values immediately after I save(*but I am not sure if the page is refreshed after saving), but not after I refresh.

controller **/application/modules/Mymodule/controllers/AdminSomesettingsController.php** :

```
class Mymodule_AdminSomesettingsController extends Core_Controller_Action_Admin
{
  public function indexAction()
  {
    $this->view->form = $form = new Mymodule_Form_Admin_Someform();

    $settings = Engine_Api::_()->getApi('settings', 'core');

    if(!$form->isValid($settings->mymodule))
    { return $form->populate($settings->mymodule); }

    if( !$this->getRequest()->isPost() ) { return; }
    if( !$form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost()) ) { return; }

    $db = Engine_Api::_()->getDbTable('settings','core')->getAdapter();
    $db->beginTransaction();
    try {
      $values = $form->getValues();
      $settings->mymodule = $values;

      $db->commit();
    } catch( Exception $e ) {
      $db->rollback();
      throw $e;
    }

    $form->saveValues();

    $form->addNotice('Your changes have been saved.');
  }
}
```

form **/application/modules/Mymodule/Form/Admin/Someform.php** :

```
class Mymodule_Form_Admin_Someform extends Engine_Form
{
  public function init()
  {
    $this
      ->setTitle('My Settings')
      ->setDescription('Settings');

    $this->addElement('Radio', 'some_setting', array(
      'label' => 'Some Setting',
      'description' => '',
      'multiOptions' => array(
        0 => 'Option One',
        1 => 'Option Two',
        2 => 'Option Three',
      ),
      'value' => 1,
      'escape' => false,
    ));

    // Add submit button
    $this->addElement('Button', 'submit', array(
      'label' => 'Save Changes',
      'type' => 'submit',
      'ignore' => true
    ));
  }
  public function saveValues()
  {
  }
}
```

I have checked with other plugins and it seems to me that `$form->populate($settings->mymodule);` repopulates the form after refresh, but it does not work for me.
Any idea how I could make it show the values from the database(*when these values exist) instead of the default values?

Answer (score 1):

I myself am new to socialengine and zend.My understanding of socialengine says, make a function saveValues() inside ur form class, then call it from controller action as **$form->saveValues()**,passing parameter as needed.This is the convention that socialengine seems to follow, and inside the saveValues() of form class,u can save valus as needed.Ur form shud be populated only if validation fails

`(!$form->isValid($formData ))
{ return $form->populate($formData); }`

Instead of **default adapter**,U should try this-

```
$db =Engine_Api::_()->getDbTable('settings','core')->getAdapter(),
$db->beginTransaction();
```

If u want to set the value of a particular field try - **$form->populate(array('formField'=>'urValue'));** in ur case maybe -

```
$val=$settings->mymodule,
$form->populate('formField'=>$val);
```

Comment: Do you mind providing a full example of one of your admin forms and it's controller? Thanks a lot.

Comment: as I said,I myself m new...lol, havnt made any admin form yet. But the process of any form is the same. I m sure $db =Engine_Api::_()->getDbTable('settings','core')->getAdapter(),will work in ur case...lets check bro.Socialengine hardly has any tutorial or so.I learnt by trial n error.Try this first see how it goes

Comment: I have tried before asking you for an example, but it didn't worked. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Did u try everything I told u...u can post the whole code of form, along with controller action portion

Comment: I have edited my question as per your instructions, or at least this is what I have understood.

Comment: As I said I m also new to socialengine, can u explain what $settings->mymodule returns? I tried things like $settings->getSetting('core.license.email') which return the value from engine4_core_settings.

Comment: UR question is also vague to me.What did u mean by -"after I refresh the page and it shows me the default values". Ur page is refreshed when u press submit,is it what u meant? I m also confused about this statement- "It shows the correct values immediately after I save(*but I am not sure if the page is refreshed after saving), but not after I refresh."

Comment: What I meant was that when I click the "Submit" button it saves the changes to the database(*I can see in the DB that they were saved). But, after I refresh the page, it shows me the default values I have set in the form(*you can see in my form example that the element has a default value set).

Comment: Regarding $settings->mymodule  .I have seen that the default plugins use this.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the code in controller $form->some_setting->setValue('1');